# How to show point.y in TrackballBehavior(builder)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have SfCartesianChart and I am showing TrackballBehavior. I want to customize it, but I don't have an idea how to get Y value in builder

this is my trackballBehavior:

```
_trackballBehavior = TrackballBehavior(
      enable: true,
      shouldAlwaysShow: true,
      lineColor: Color(0xFF454545),
      activationMode: ActivationMode.singleTap,
      tooltipDisplayMode: TrackballDisplayMode.nearestPoint,
      builder: (context, TrackballDetails trackballDetails) {
        log(trackballDetails.point.toString()); // Instance of 'CartesianChartPoint<dynamic>'
        return Container(
          child: Text(
            "point.y",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
            )
        ));
      },
```

I tried trackballDetails.series and others but it returns me an instance or null or index

But I want to get a value of Y axis

If I use point.y in format then everything works but I can't customize it. How to fix trackballDetails.series or trackballDetails.point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I find the solution:

```
trackballDetails.point?.yValue != null ?trackballDetails.point!.yValue.toString() : trackballDetails.point!.high.toString(),
```

//This checking null helps to solve the problem if you meet null in your value